# How to ignore some commas not inside quotes when using pandas.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
ID,name,category,main_category,currency,deadline,goal,launched,pledged,state,backers,country,usd pledged
1009317190,French Cuisine, A Traditional Experience,Cookbooks,Food,USD,2014-09-08 00:46:23,13730,2014-08-09 03:16:02,3984,failed,46,US,3984
```

I used `pandas.read_csv()` to load the csv file above to dataframe. However, my output came like this:

[image: dataframe]

*Question:* How can I ignore the comma between `French Cuisine` and `A Traditional Experience`, and read them into the same column?

Comment: Although there are ways to do this, it should be the generation of this csv that should be fixed as it is not correctly formatted.

Comment: Agreed. The whole string should be put in double quotes in the input csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these steps to achieve what you want:

Step1:

```
df['name'] = df['name']+df['category']
```

[image]

Step2:

```
data1 = df.iloc[:, :2] # dataframe with columns 'ID' and 'name'
data2 = df.iloc[:, 2:].T.shift(-1,axis=0).T # Shifting multi-column data to the left    
data = pd.concat([data1, data2], axis=1)    # concat dataframes data1 and data2 along columns
```

[image]

Step3:

```
data = data.drop('Unnamed:13', 1) # drop column named 'Unnamed:13'
```

[image]

Comment: I am glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the CSV file as a text file and replace `French Cuisine, A Traditional Experience` by `French Cuisine A Traditional Experience`.

```
csv_file = open("example.csv", 'r').read()
csv_file = csv_file.replace("French Cuisine, A Traditional Experience", "French Cuisine A Traditional Experience")

open("example.csv", 'w').write(csv_file)
```